# Column "rate" must be length 1 (a summary value), not 22906

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having some troubles with the below code. It returns

> "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column rate must be length 1 (a summary value), not 22906"

Is there any problem with my code?

`sub_grade` is of type character and `int_rate` is numeric

```
results <- loan_data %>%
  select(credit_grade, sub_grade, int_rate, loan_amnt) %>%
  group_by(sub_grade) %>%
  summarise(
    rate = substr(int_rate * 100, 1, 4),
    nr_loans = n(),
    "&",
    percent1 = substr((nr_loans / a) * 100, 1, 5),
    klj = "&",
    Amount = sum(loan_amnt, na.rm = TRUE),
    klj1 = "&",
    percent2 = substr((Amount / total) * 100, 1, 5)
  )
```

The problem shows up only when I add the first variable `rate`.

Reproducible example:

```
sub_grade <- c("A1", "A2", "A3","A1","A3")
int_rate <– c(0.023, 0.027, 0.033,0.023,0.033)
```

what I want is

```
sub_grade.  int_rate
```

1. A1.           0.023
2. A2.           0.027
3. A3.           0.033

Comment: Yes. The problem is that `summarise` expects only 1 value per group. But, `rate = substr(int_rate * 100, 1, 4)` will return value for every row. You need to think some grouping function like `min, max etc` before using substr.

Comment: Even, I can see there are more problems afterwards. It would be better to add a reproducible example and expected output as part of your question.

Comment: @MKR for each group of the sub_grade variable there is a certain interest rate. For example for the group A1 the int  rate is 2.35%, for A2 it is 2.73% and so on. What I want to do is just to show the interest rate for each group. it should not be smth hard but just I do not see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've previously resolved the same problem by using mutate instead of sumamrise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `dplyr::summarise` expects/accepts one value per group. But the `substr(int_rate*100, ...)` in your code will return value for each row i.e. many value per group. You need to think of using some grouping functions like `min, max, first, last etc` as part of `substr`. Considering the sample data that OP has posted the solution could be as:

```
# Data
sub_grade <- c("A1", "A2", "A3","A1","A3")
int_rate <- c(0.023, 0.027,0.033,0.023,0.033)

loan_data <- data.frame(sub_grade, int_rate, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use dplyr to summarise on sub_grade
library(dplyr)
loan_data %>% group_by(sub_grade) %>%
  summarise(int_rate = first(int_rate)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   sub_grade int_rate
# 1        A1    0.023
# 2        A2    0.027
# 3        A3    0.033
```

Comment: Generally `first` or equivalent is a sign there's a more robust way to write the code. Usually it means that the variable should be a grouping variable, but in this case there wouldn't be any thing so summarise at that point, so you could just do `loan_data %>% select(sub_grade, int_rate) %>% distinct()` or in this particular case, just `distinct(loan_data)`