# Is there an R function mirroring EXCEL COUNTIFS with date range as condition?

Tags: r, date, countif

I currently face the following issue.

I want to come up with an R code that creates a new column called, e.g., `reviews_last30days` in my main dataframe `listings` which should be able to count or accumulate all reviews for each unique `listings$ID`.

The unique reviews per ID are listed in another dataframe like this:

```
REVIEWS
   ID   review_date
   1    2015-12-30
   1    2015-12-31
   1    2016-10-27
   2    2014-05-10
   2    2016-10-19
   2    2016-10-22
   2    2016-10-23
```

I also need to add a date condition, e.g. such that only the last 30 days starting from the `last_scrape` are considered.

*Hence my result should look somewhat like the third column:(UPDATE: see EDIT for better description of intended result)*

```
LISTINGS
   ID   last_scrape   reviews_last30days
   1    2016-11-15    1
   2    2016-11-15    3
```

So finally, the column `reviews_last30days` should count `review_date` for each `ID` since the indicated time frame of 30 days since the `last_scape`.

I already formatted both date columns "as.Date" with "%Y-%m-%d".

Sorry if my problem might not be formulated clearly enough for you guys, it's quite hard to explain or visualize, but in terms of code it hopefully shouldn't be that complicated after all.

### EDIT for clarification

Besides the input REVIEWS indicated above, I do have a second input dataframe, be it OVERVIEW, that currently looks somewhat like this in a simplified form:

```
OVERVIEW
   ID   last_scrape
   1    2016-11-15
   2    2016-11-15
   3    2016-11-15
   4    2017-01-15
   5    2017-01-15
   6    2017-01-15
   7    2017-01-15
etc
```

So what I actually need is a code to count all entries of `review_date` for which the `ID` from OVERVIEW matches with the `ID` in REVIEWS and the `review_date` from REVIEWS is max 30 days from the `last_scrape` in OVERVIEW.

The code should then ideally assign this newly calculated value as new column in OVERVIEW like this:

```
OVERVIEW
   ID   last_scrape   rev_last30days
   1    2016-11-15    1
   2    2016-11-15    3
   3    2016-11-15    ..
   4    2017-01-15    ..
   5    2017-01-15    ..
   6    2017-01-15    ..
   7    2017-01-15    ..
etc
```

### #2 EDIT - hopefully my last ;)

Thanks for your help so far @mfidino! Plotting your latest code still results in one minor mistake, namely the following:

```
TOTALREV$review_date <- ymd(TOTALREV$review_date)

    TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc <- ymd(TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc)

    gen_listings <- function(review = NULL, overview = NULL){
      # tibble to return
      to_return <- review %>% 
        inner_join(., overview, by = 'listing_id') %>% 
        group_by(listing_id) %>% 
        summarise(last_scraped.calc = unique(last_scraped.calc),
                  reviews_last30days = sum(review_date >= (last_scraped.calc-30)))
      return(to_return)
    }

    REVIEWCOUNT <- gen_listings(TOTALREV, TOTALLISTINGS)

Error: Column `last_scraped.calc` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this error?

NOTE:
I used the names as in my original file, code should still be the same.

If it helps, some properties of the vector `last_scraped.calc`:

```
$ last_scraped.calc   : Date, format: "2018-08-07" "2018-08-07" ...
```

```
typeof(TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc)
[1] "double"
```

```
length(TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc)
[1] 549281
```

and

```
unique(TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc)
 [1] "2018-08-07" "2019-01-13" "2018-08-15" "2019-01-16" "2018-08-14" 
"2019-01-15" "2019-01-14" "2019-01-22" [9] "2018-08-22" "2018-08-21" 
"2019-01-28" "2018-08-20" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-31" "2018-08-09" 
"2018-08-10" [17] "2018-08-08" "2018-08-16"
```

Any further help much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with `dplyr`. I am using `lubridate::ymd()` here instead of `as.Date()` as well.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

REVIEWS <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
             review_date = c("2015-12-30",
                             "2015-12-31",
                             "2016-10-27",
                             "2014-05-10",
                             "2016-10-19",
                             "2016-10-22",
                             "2016-10-23"))

REVIEWS$review_date <- ymd(REVIEWS$review_date)

LISTINGS <- REVIEWS %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
              summarise(last_scrape = max(review_date),
              reviews_last30days = sum(review_date >= (max(review_date)-30)))
```

The output of `LISTINGS` is your expected output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     ID last_scrape reviews_last30days
  <dbl> <date>                   <int>
1     1 2016-10-27                   1
2     2 2016-10-23                   3
```

EDIT:

If, instead, you are interested in letting `last_scrape` be an input rather than the latest review date per group, you can modify the code as such. Assuming that there can be multiple `last_scrape` per ID:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

REVIEWS <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
             review_date = c("2015-12-30",
                             "2015-12-31",
                             "2016-10-27",
                             "2014-05-10",
                             "2016-10-19",
                             "2016-10-22",
                             "2016-10-23"))

REVIEWS$review_date <- ymd(REVIEWS$review_date)

OVERVIEW <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:7, 2),
                       last_scrape = c("2016-11-15",
                                       "2016-11-15",
                                       "2016-11-15",
                                       "2017-01-15",
                                       "2017-01-15",
                                       "2017-01-15",
                                       "2017-01-15",
                                       "2016-11-20",
                                       "2016-11-20",
                                       "2016-11-20",
                                       "2017-01-20",
                                       "2017-01-20",
                                       "2017-01-20",
                                       "2017-01-20"))

OVERVIEW$last_scrape <- ymd(OVERVIEW$last_scrape)

gen_listings <- function(review = NULL, overview = NULL){
  # tibble to return
  to_return <- review %>% 
    inner_join(., overview, by ='ID') %>% 
    group_by(ID, last_scrape) %>% 
    summarise(
    reviews_last30days = sum(review_date >= (last_scrape-30)))
  return(to_return)
}

LISTINGS <- gen_listings(REVIEWS, OVERVIEW)
```

The output of this `LISTINGS` object is:

```
     ID last_scrape reviews_last30days
  <dbl> <date>                   <int>
1     1 2016-11-15                   1
2     1 2016-11-20                   1
3     2 2016-11-15                   3
4     2 2016-11-20                   2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! What I think still does not match my requirements would be the part with ```last_scrape = max(review_date)```.

Since ```last_scrape``` is not meant to yield the latest date of the review date, but it rather indicates the GIVEN value of the last scrape and this date should then be used as reference for counting 30 days back. 

Do you know what I mean? Also, once again thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but your question does not actually reflect that. I'll modify the code to accept an input for `last_scrape`.

Comment: Hey mfidino, yeah I was afraid I didn't describe it correclty - thanks so much for your edit! I adapted the code and I'm getting much closer to my solution, only now I am still struggling with the limitation that in your code ```last_scrape``` must be of length 1 since ```dplyr::summarise```expects one value per group. My data however has multiple values for ```last_scrape``` (which is currently a date column in the LISTINGS table serving as second input and allocating a date to each ID) and thus needs to be matched via ```ID```. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I just EDITED my original entry to be more clear about my actual problem, hope that helps as well in understanding :)

Comment: That makes perfect sense @giannis.mvp. Thank you for updating the question. The changes I made should work now. It only works for cases where you have the `ID` in both data.frames (i.e., it excludes ones where there is not a match.

Comment: wow, awesome how fast you respond. I think we almost got to where I wanted, just posted a minor flaw in my second edit - do you have any idea maybe?

Comment: Are there multiple records per `ID` in the `OVERVIEW` object? If so, which one are you looking to obtain for each `ID`?

Comment: Yes, atm there are exactly two records per ```ID``` since I have like semi-annual scrapings of the data and I am actually trying to obtain both. Workaround might be to disaggregate the data for each scrape such that there's only one record for each ```ID``` in OVERVIEW, run your code and then join afterwards..?!

Comment: Okay. The code can now account for any number of records per `ID` in the `OVERVIEW` object.

Comment: No problem. If it works @giannis.mvp please upvote the answer so that it can be marked as accepted.

Comment: Sorry to open this up again, but I had to pull new csvs for analysis and now the code does not work anymore, i.e. my output of ```LISTINGS``` object is now only 1 number seeming to cumulate all ```reviews_last30days``` without grouping by ID or last_scrape :/

Comment: Also when i plugged in your code from above with the examplary dataframes, R produces only one number as output for ```LISTINGS```, i.e. "7" without grouping by  ID or last_scrape - any ideas?

Comment: If you have a new problem, it would be much better to open up a new question  (and link back to this question within it). However, your problem looks to be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781829/column-rate-must-be-length-1-a-summary-value-not-22906. My previous solution works with the example you provided and may not generalize to all other types of data you have, so the issue must be with the new data you are providing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing the link, i just wasnt sure whether my issue was worth opening up an entirely new question since I only added a few more rows to the dataframe which is still other than that the same as before

Comment: I am just wondering why when copying your exact same code R now gives a single number as output for ```LISTINGS``` instead of the output of the object as you indicated above, thats what confuses me most and I think understanding this would be the easiest way to solve my original problem

Comment: Have you tried using my most recent code instead? It looks like the 2nd edit you provided only groups by `listing_id` whereas my code that takes in the `OVERVIEW` object groups by `listing_id` and `last_scrape`. You are getting this error because you have multiple `last_scraped.calc` per listing ID. If the most recent code does not work it is because you are having a different problem entirely and should post another question to address that specific issue instead of changing your question within this one.

Comment: Yes, I tried plugging in your entire recent code incl. the values for the dataframes you provided and still get only one number instead of your proposed output - but thanks, I will ask about my problem in a separate question!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answer...

```
REV %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(rev_latest = max(review_date)) %>%
  filter(rev_latest - review_date < 30) %>%
  count(ID)
```