# R function mirroring COUNTIFS produces wrong result

Tags: r, countif

the result I want to come up with has previously been dealt with already in this question: [Is there an R function mirroring EXCEL COUNTIFS with date range as condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023458/is-there-an-r-function-mirroring-excel-countifs-with-date-range-as-condition)

I've got two separate dataframes as input: `TOTALREV` and `TOTALLISTINGS`, both of which look like this in a simplified form:

```
TOTALREV
listing_id reviewer_id reviewer_name review_date
1       2818       10952           Lam  2009-03-30
2       2818       12798         Alice  2009-04-24
3       2818       11869       Natalja  2009-05-03
4       2818       14064       Enrique  2009-05-18
5       2818       17977       Sherwin  2009-05-25
6       2818       20192           Jie  2009-06-29
```

and

```
TOTALLISTINGS
listing_id last_scraped.calc
1       2818        2019-03-07
2      20168        2019-03-07
3      25428        2019-03-07
4      27886        2019-03-07
5      28658        2019-03-07
6      28871        2019-03-07
```

Please note that I do have multiple `last_scraped.calc` per `listing_id`

So what I actually need is a code to count all entries of `review_date` for which the `listing_id` from `TOTALLISTINGS` matches with the `listing_id` in `TOTALREV` and the `review_date`from `TOTALREV` is max 30 days from the respective `last_scraped.calc` in `TOTALLISTINGS`

Such that my intended output would be:

```
REVIEWCOUNT
listing_id last_scraped.calc reviews_last30
  <dbl>    <date>                   <int>
1     1   2016-11-15                   1
2     1   2016-11-20                   1
3     2   2016-11-15                   3
4     2   2016-11-20                   2
```

In the previous thread "mfidino" already helped me in coming up with the following code which used to work fine until i compiled some extra data of the exact same type:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

genlistings <- function(TOTALLISTINGS = NULL, TOTALREV = NULL){
      # tibble to return
      to_return <- TOTALREV %>%
        inner_join(., TOTALLISTINGS, by ='listing_id') %>% 
        group_by(listing_id, last_scraped.calc) %>% 
        summarise(
          reviews_last30 = sum((review_date >= (last_scraped.calc-30) & (review_date <= last_scraped.calc))))
      return(to_return)
    }

    REVIEWCOUNT <- genlistings(TOTALREV, TOTALLISTINGS)
```

However when running the above code now, my R returns only the following instead of the proposed output as indicated above with `REVIEWCOUNT`:

```
head(REVIEWCOUNT)
  reviews_last30
1        1018668
```

So unfortunately I think the code does not really group by `listing_id` or `last_scraped.calc` and only sum up all reviews for which the above condition is true.

Any help is much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could first `merge` both tables and then use `table` on those which are not older than 30 days to get the frequency. (I have changed max days from 30 to 3580 to get an output from your sample data.)

```
TOTALREV <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="listing_id reviewer_id reviewer_name review_date
1       2818       10952           Lam  2009-03-30
2       2818       12798         Alice  2009-04-24
3       2818       11869       Natalja  2009-05-03
4       2818       14064       Enrique  2009-05-18
5       2818       17977       Sherwin  2009-05-25
6       2818       20192           Jie  2009-06-29")

TOTALLISTINGS <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="listing_id last_scraped.calc
1       2818        2019-03-07
2      20168        2019-03-07
3      25428        2019-03-07
4      27886        2019-03-07
5      28658        2019-03-07
6      28871        2019-03-07")

#Change to Date to allow calculating difference
TOTALREV$review_date <- as.Date(TOTALREV$review_date)
TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc <- as.Date(TOTALLISTINGS$last_scraped.calc)

me <- merge(TOTALREV, TOTALLISTINGS,)
#maxDays <- 30
maxDays <- 3580
data.frame(with(me[me$review_date - me$last_scraped.calc <= 0 & me$review_date - me$last_scraped.calc >= -maxDays,], table(listing_id, last_scraped.calc)))
#  listing_id last_scraped.calc Freq
#1       2818        2019-03-07    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea! this already feels like a good approach to my problem. Merging both dataframes results in R cumulating all review_date for each listing_id and for each last_scraped.calc since I have multiple last_scraped.calc per listing_id which looks like a reasonable step. 

However, using ```table``` as second step does not result in my intended output as R now lists way more and different dates for ```last_scraped.calc``` as there have been before.

Comment: `table` can only give dates which have been in `me`, but there was a bug in the selection before. It looks in both directions in time and not only back. I have updated this and hope that it works now as you expect.